# Zend Lucene doesn't index special characters (although Common_Utf8Num_CaseInsensitive is used)

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene

although I use one of the UTF8 analysers, Lucene doesn't treat special characters (like ë, which is a common character in dutch) well. 
Testing on Windows with a local Xampp installation learns me that ë is stored by lucene as Ã«

On my live-site (linux-server) things are even worse: Lucene stops indexing a string completely when it encounters a character like ë.

I just don't understand what I am doing wrong.
Hopefully someone can shed some light...

Comment: other example &nbsp; is stored as Â, with or without the use of html_entity_decode()

Answer (score 1):

To make Zend Lucene correctly encode Dutch, locale needs to be set to Dutch:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'nl_NL.utf8')
```

or

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL.utf8')
```

I had done this, but it turned out that this locale wasn't installed on the server where I host my website.

You can check this by checking the return value of `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'nl_NL.utf8')`. If it returns false, the locale isn't installed.